# reading form value of a control (TextBox) in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, httprequest

I would like to read the `Form` value of a control (e.g TextBox), i.e '`Request.Form["[Control_Name_Here]"]`.  The problem with using say `TextBox.Text` is because if you explicity set it yourself in the `Page_Load`, there is no way you can get back the 'original value' submitted in the form.

As you know, Asp.Net generates a unique ID/Name for the control. The Request.Form is based on the `name` attribute of a control.  Each webcontrol has a `ClientID` property, however this does not match the name.  The name seems to be almost like the ClientID, having $ instead of _.  Is there a way to easily get the value from the form, without resorting to having to replace the _ to a $?

And this should also cater for other naming-conventions, because as from Asp.Net you can also choose to have a control's id statically-generated, rather than dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're not looking for the `.ClientID` property, but the `.UniqueID` property of the Control.

See: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d04y8ss.aspx)

Edit: Also, is there a reason you're always setting the `.Text` property within the page load? Instead of for example check the `Page.IsPostBack` property instead and only set the `.Text` if it's `false`?

Answer (score -1):

I personally use jquery to find the control and read and set the value

GetFormValue = function (idName) {
    var srchP = '*[id*='+idName+']';
    var ctrl = $(srchP);

```
if (ctrl != null)
    return ctrl.val();
return null;
```

}
so assume th id name in server part is txMytext
and it will be .....$txMytext in client
and by calling GetFormValue('txMytext') in client side you cna get the value of control

dont foget to use jquery library

Comment: It is server-side, not client side. JQuery works on the client-side.